# Determining if an object is up or down

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, topology

I am trying to determine if this object is upward or downward.
Object in question: [image: Part to help visualize] (shot with phone)

Problem: I cannot determine if the part is flipped right side up or right side down

The ones with the back light are cropped using cv2.minAreaRect so this is the true resolution of what the camera sees.

Work area:

- Camera resolution: 2592 (H) × 1944 (V)
- Camera is 15-18 inches above the tray (can be moved)
- 2 Trays side by side both 6x9 inches with a
  back light

[image: Hump Down]
<<< This image has no local lighting and the hump is down. This finds contours, XY, and rotation.

[image: Hump Down AND LIGHT]
<<< In this image I added local lighting and the hump is down. The idea was to threshold the image and detect the ridge but since the local lighting is fixed, orientation effects the light reaching the ridge leading to inconsistent data.

[image: Hump Down with no light or back light]
<<< This was an image taken with no back light and with my phone. Hump is down (reference image).

[image: Hump Up]
<<< This is the same but the hump is up and only a back light.

[image: Hump Up AND LIGHT]
<<< Hump is up back light and local light

[image: Hump Up with no light or back light]
<<< Hump is up (reference image)

Comment: Not a image processing guy but I am pretty sure to do this you either need a ton of training data for a ML model or at least have a consistent lighting position (such as putting a light source on the right to have a constant shadow to the left which can be used to tell which way it is flipped). I can't imagine a program doing this properly without one of  those two conditions because it is even hard for my eyes to tell some of those pictures apart.

Comment: Yes I agree! Ideally I would like to have this done in the next four days. But I doubt can build and train a whole ML algorithm in that time frame. I've been learning but damn it is a new concept.

Comment: I would just put a light on the side. Or maybe using something like a laser point to give you a reference.

Comment: @JordanTaranto Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65429116/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There is **no general solution**, but I guess if you do **Hough Circular Transform** to detect the circle position and compare that to the middle of the image, you might have a special solution to this case:

[image: result]

```py
# Import Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray, gray2rgb
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter

# Read image
img = imread('21.png')

# RGB to Gray
raw = rgb2gray(img)

# Edge detector
edges = canny(raw)

# Detect two radii
hough_radii = np.arange(5, 25, 2)
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)


# Select the most prominent 3 circles
accums, cx, cy, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii,
                                           total_num_peaks=1)
# Check wither shape is up or down
if(cy > raw.shape[0]//2):
    pos = "shape is down"
else:
    pos = "shape is up"

# Draw them
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 4))
image = gray2rgb(raw)
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius,
                                    shape=image.shape)
    image[circy, circx] = (220, 20, 20)

image[image.shape[0]//2,...] = (255,0,0)

ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[0].set_title('Original')
ax[0].axis('off')

ax[1].imshow(image)
ax[1].set_title(pos)
ax[1].axis('off')

plt.show()
```